# Foreach com Lambda não funciona

Tags: java, loop, expressões-lambda, java-8

Tenho uma lista de objetos que quero percorrer, mas está dando erro e não estou entendendo o porque:

```
    listaAtendimento.stream().forEach(atendimentoFicha ->
    {   
        fichaAtend.getAtendimentosIndividuais().add(getAtendIndivChild(jTxtLog, atendimentoFicha));
    });
```

o erro é esse

> local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

Alguém pode me explicar por que ali dá erro agora se no código a baixo não ocorre?

```
    List <String> teste = new ArrayList<>();
    listaAtendimento.stream().forEach(atendimentoFicha ->
    {   
     teste.add(atendimentoFicha.getId)));
    });
```

Comment: Como `jTxtLog` e `fichaAtend` são declarados e onde eles são usados?

Comment: É exatamente o que o erro diz. Você não pode iterar ou modificar variaveis de fora do foreach. Elas precisam ser "final". Mas com "final", não quero dizer realmente uma variável declarada como "final", e sim algo que não terá seu valor modificado dentro do foreach. Nesse link tem uma resposta muito boa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Até o Java 7, usar variáveis do escopo local externo dentro de classes anônimas não funcionava se elas não fossem `final`:

```
public void metodoQualquer() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 7;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(a + b); // Erro de compilação aqui!
        }
    });
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Ignora a exceção.
    }
}
```

O motivo é que as variáveis locais são alocadas no *stack frame* da chamada de método local, e nada garante que quando o método da classe anônima for executada, que esse *stack frame* ainda existirá. Entretanto, se a variável for declada `final`, então o compilador poderá sintetizar um construtor da classe anônima responsável por fazer a cópia destes valores, e uma vez que são `final`, então o valor usado dentro da classe anônima sempre vai refletir o valor do *stack frame*. Assim, o código acima poderia ser reescrito desta forma:

```
public void metodoQualquer() {
    final int a = 5;
    final int b = 7;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(a + b); // Agora não dá erro de compilação aqui.
        }
    });
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Ignora a exceção.
    }
}
```

O Java 8 herda esta mesma regra na implementação dos *lambdas*. Entretanto, uma vez que ser obrigado a ficar sempre declarando o `final` é muito chato, surgiu o conceito do *effectively final*, que significa basicamente que se a variável não sofrer modificação do seu valor, mesmo se o modificador `final` não estiver presente, então para todos os efeitos práticos é como se ela de fato tivesse o modificador `final`. Assim, no Java 8 eu posso escrever o código acima desta forma:

```
public void metodoQualquer() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 7;

    // Não dá erro de compilação aqui, mesmo que o a e o b não tenham sido declarados como final.
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> System.out.println(a + b));
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Ignora a exceção.
    }
}
```

Entretanto, se a variável puder ser modificada (ou seja, não puder ser considerada implicitamente como `final`), aí o esquema já não funciona mais:

```
public void metodoQualquer() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 7;

    // Erro de compilação aqui, a não é final ou effectively final.
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> a = a + b);
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Ignora a exceção.
    }
}
```

No seu caso, pelo menos uma das variáveis `fichaAtend` ou `jTxtLog` não é *effectively final*, pois pelo menos uma delas é uma variável local que não tem o modificador `final` e que também sofre modificaçãoes após ter o seu valor atribuído pela primeira vez.

Há quatro soluções para isso. Escolha a que for melhor para você:

1. A primeira solução é mudar a estrutura do escopo externo para garantir que essas variáveis sejam `final` ou *effectively final*.
2. A segunda solução é declarar uma outra variável *effectively final* e atribuir o valor destas variáveis:

   ```
   TipoDoFichaAtend fichaAtend2 = fichaAtend;
   TipoDoJTxtLog jTxtLog2 = jTxtLog;
   listaAtendimento.stream().forEach(atendimentoFicha ->
   {   
       fichaAtend2.getAtendimentosIndividuais().add(getAtendIndivChild(jTxtLog2, atendimentoFicha));
   });
   ```
3. Há casos aonde a segunda solução não é adwquada, pois ela só funciona se o valor da variável não sofrer mais modificações no escopo externo ou se estas modificações não devam ser refletidas no escopo interno. Também não funciona se o escopo interno modificar as variáveis do escopo externo. Neste caso, temos uma terceira solução, que é encapsular o valor em um objeto mutável armazenado em uma variável *effectively final*. O tipo [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) é um bom candidato a isso:

   ```
   AtomicReference<TipoDoFichaAtend> fichaAtend2 = new AtomicReference<>(fichaAtend);
   AtomicReference<TipoDoJTxtLog> jTxtLog2 = new AtomicReference<>(jTxtLog);
   listaAtendimento.stream().forEach(atendimentoFicha ->
   {   
       fichaAtend2.get().getAtendimentosIndividuais().add(getAtendIndivChild(jTxtLog2.get(), atendimentoFicha));
       jTxtLog2.set(oQueVoceQuiser); // Exemplo de modificação do conteúdo da variável.
   });
   TipoDoJTxtLog resultado = jTxtLog2.get(); // Trará o resultado após modificações no escopo interno.
   ```

   Uma outra alternativa ao `AtomicReference` mais simples, mas mais *gambiarrosa* e que não é *thread-safe*, é usar um array de uma única posição para encapsular o objeto:

   ```
   TipoDoFichaAtend[] fichaAtend2 = {fichaAtend};
   TipoDoJTxtLog[] jTxtLog2 = {jTxtLog};
   listaAtendimento.stream().forEach(atendimentoFicha ->
   {   
       fichaAtend2[0].getAtendimentosIndividuais().add(getAtendIndivChild(jTxtLog2[0], atendimentoFicha));
       jTxtLog2[0] = oQueVoceQuiser; // Exemplo de modificação do conteúdo da variável.
   });
   TipoDoJTxtLog resultado = jTxtLog2[0]; // Trará o resultado após modificações no escopo interno.
   ```
4. A última solução é reestruturar o seu código de forma que ele não precise mais usar o *lambda*. Essa situação é limitada e nem sempre pode ser aplicada, mas é frequente no caso de *lambdas* que podem ser substituídos por laços *for* ou *enhanced-for*.

Para finalizar, no último exemplo que você deu, a única variável do escopo externo que é usada no escopo interno é a variável `teste`, que é *effectively final* porque o seu valor só é atribuído uma única vez. E por causa disso, o código desse exemplo compila.

Comment: era isso que queria saber. muito obrigado... no caso pra resolver este problema, tive que desistir de usar esta frescura de Lambda e usar o for classico   
`for (FichaAtendIndividual atendimentoFicha : listaAtendimento)   {fichaAtend.getAtendimentosIndividuais().add(getAtendIndivChild(jTxtLog, atendimentoFicha));}`